# Calculating efficiency of a C program

Tags: c, performance, coding-efficiency

I was writing some code and had to calculate the efficiency, but I'm struggling. I just called them function "f" for convenience. These 2 are not related:

```
int f(int a, int b) {
  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = a; i > 1; i /= 2) {
    if (i % 2) {
      ans += b;
    }
    b += b;
  }
  return ans;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////
int f(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; ++j) {
      count += i * j;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < i * n; ++k) {
      count -= k;
    }
  }
  
  return count;
}
```

For the first one, I thought it was O(nlogn), since i is based on a and there are 2 operations, the if statement and the update. For the second one it should be O(n^2) since there is a nested loop. Let me know if I did it right, thanks.

Comment: Easy way to find out: Benchmark for various values of *N*, like 1, 10, 100, etc. up by powers of 10 until it's taking too long. Record the times and find out how to approximate that curve with a function.

Comment: Nested loops are usually automatically *O(N^2)*. The only time you get *log N* is in cases where you're cutting the iterations geometrically, not linearly. A binary search cuts down logarithmically, starting the iterations at `j` does not.

Comment: What is `n` (from `O(nlogn)`) in `int f(int a, int b)`?

Comment: Sorry I have a new program here
https://imgur.com/a/QnpFSY3
I wanted to add the code to the post but failed to edit the post. This involves recursion so I'm struggling a bit. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function is O(log a) because the only loop is begins at `a` and the value is halved in each iteration.

The second function is O(n^3) because the outer loop is `n` times and the (larger) inner loop is `i*n` times.

Comment: Thank you, I just have one more that I can't figure out. I've updated the question

Comment: The code is here:
https://imgur.com/a/QnpFSY3
I failed to edit the post. I'm struggling with evaluating this one since it's based on recursion. Thank you

Comment: (one of) the worst case is that all elements of array `a` has the same value. In this case, There will be two `f(a, len - 1)` calls from each `f(a, len)` call, so it will be O(2^len).